# IE7 and fixed divs problem

Tags: css, layout, fixed, incompatibility

#### Background

I need to do a rather complex layout for a client, using fixed DIV. Everything is fine in IE8, FF3 and Chrome, but IE7 mangles all the thing

Edit: **The fixed DIVs are a must, only the content DIV must scroll (That is the spec, sorry)**

#### HTML and CSS code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /><title>
    test
</title>

    <!--[if lt IE 8]>

    <![endif]--> 

    <!--[if lt IE 7]>

    <![endif]--> 

</head>

<body style="margin: 10px;">
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;  border: 1px solid red; overflow: hidden;">

    <div id="header" style="position: fixed; width: 185px;  height: 600px;  top: 10px;  border: 1px solid blue;">
      header
    </div>

    <div id="content" style="width: 680px; float: left; background: white; margin-left: 185px;  min-height: 600px;  border: 1px solid lime;">
        content
    </div>

    <div id="rightcolumn" style="position: fixed; top: 10px; width: 90px; margin-left: 865px;   height: 600px;border: 1px solid maroon;">
        right
    </div>

</div> 


</body>
</html>
```

#### Width IE8, FF3 and Chrome

[IE8, FF3 and Chrome http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/406/firefoxkpd.jpg](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/406/firefoxkpd.jpg)

#### Width IE7

[IE7 http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/1315/ie7l.jpg](http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/1315/ie7l.jpg)

#### Notes

I'm not so worried about IE6 because I know it does not support `Fixed` elements, but if you know how to fix it, great!

#### Questions

1. What should I know about IE7 bugs to fix the problem?
2. How can I reference the left in the header columns relatively to the wrapper
3. Why the header column goes the the right and the right column disappears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found a fix!!** Strange enough floating the content to `right` fixes it!
Do I earn a cookie?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /><title>
    test
</title>

    <!--[if lt IE 8]>

    <![endif]--> 

    <!--[if lt IE 7]>

    <![endif]--> 

</head>

<body style="margin: 10px;">
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;  border: 1px solid red; overflow: hidden;">

    <div id="header" style="position: fixed; width: 185px; height: 600px;   top: 10px; border: 1px solid blue;">
      header
    </div>

    <div id="content" style="float: right; width: 680px; margin-right: 90px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid lime;">
        content
    </div>    

    <div id="rightcolumn" style="position: fixed; top: 10px; width: 90px; margin-left: 865px;   height: 600px;border: 1px solid maroon;">
        right
    </div>


</div> 


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /><title>
    test
</title>

    <!--[if lt IE 8]>

    <![endif]--> 

    <!--[if lt IE 7]>

    <![endif]--> 

</head>

<body style="margin: 10px;">
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;  border: 1px solid red; overflow: hidden;">

    <div id="header" style="float: left; width: 185px;  height: 600px;      top: 10px;      border: 1px solid blue;">
      header
    </div>

    <div id="content" style="width: 650px; float: left; background: white; left: 185px;  min-height: 600px; height: 600px;      border: 1px solid lime;">
        content
    </div>

    <div id="rightcolumn" style="float: left; top: 10px; width: 90px; left: 865px;   height: 600px;border: 1px solid maroon;">
        right
    </div>

</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

It works on IE7, Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome. I guess it will work in IE6 and IE8 too.
I had to reduce the width of the "content" because the (rightcolumn+content+header) < wrapper

Comment: I didn't used "fixed" divs, but I guess that it's not a must if it works. Is it?

Comment: Your solution failed to render properly. I tried it on a 24" monitor running IE7. There is an extra right hand column.

Comment: It's not an extra right column, it's the wrapper which is bigger than all the child divs. (185+650+90)=925 > 960

Answer (score 0):

The fixed position doesn't work in older browsers. You can float the elements beside each other.

Specify a zero padding for the body also, Opera uses a default padding instead of margin (which actually makes more sense).

I put the styles in a style sheet to make the code cleaner:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>test</title>

<style type="text/css">
body { margin: 10px; padding: 0; }
#wrapper { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid red; overflow: hidden; }
#header { float: left; width: 185px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid blue; }
#content { float: left; width: 680px; background: white; min-height: 600px; border: 1px solid lime; }
#rightcolumn { float: left; width: 89px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid maroon; }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="header">
      header
   </div>
   <div id="content">
      content
   </div>
   <div id="rightcolumn">
      right
   </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is with the *fixed* columns. I do not consider IE7 an "older browser" and it supports Fixed divs (or at least that is what the manual says)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /><title>
    test
</title>

    <!--[if lt IE 8]>

    <![endif]--> 

    <!--[if lt IE 7]>

    <![endif]--> 

</head>

<body style="margin: 10px;">
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;  border: 1px solid red; overflow: hidden;">

    <div id="header" style="width: 185px; float: left;  height: 600px;      top: 10px;      border: 1px solid blue;">
      header
    </div>

    <div id="content" style="width: 680px; float: center; background: white; margin-left: 185px;  min-height: 600px;      border: 1px solid lime;">
        content
    </div>

    <div id="rightcolumn" style="position: fixed; top: 10px; width: 95px; margin-left: 865px;   height: 600px;border: 1px solid maroon;">
        right
    </div>

</div> 


</body>
</html>
```

That should do it!

Answer (score 0):

If script-based solutions are acceptable, then I have had some success with fixed divs (not necessarily using the layout you have) using Dean Edwards' [upgrade scripts](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) which patch IE behaviours to be more like the standards indicate.

Comment: I tried it, but does not work. The thing is that allegedly IE7 supports Fixed DIVs, but don't know how to keep the header on the left and the right column on the right.